# Change SVGs 'style' element in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, stylesheet

I have a SVG which contains a bit of css. I want to change the `style` element in this SVG, with javascript, but in IE/Edge you can;t change the `style` element with `.innerHTML`. Instead, you need `.styleSheet.cssText`, but I cant get it to work in my SVG.

This works in non-IE browsers, to get and set the value:

```
var style  = document.getElementById('example').contentDocument.querySelector("style");
style.innerHTML = style.innerHTML.replace('foo', 'bar')
```

The SVG (simplified):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 540 494.08">
    <defs>
        <style id="SvgStyleSheet">
            .someClass{}
        </style>
        <!-- Some more definitions -->
    </defs>
    <!-- SVG elements here -->
</svg>
```

**How do I get and set the style in this SVG?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was very very close with `.styleSheets.cssText`, had to use it slightly different.

In order to keep it working in IE/Edge, Firefox, Android, Chrome and iPhone's browser, I had to implement both.

```
var svgDOC = document.getElementById('idOfSVG').contentDocument;

style = svgDOC.styleSheets[0];
// IE/Edge
if( typeof style.cssText !== "undefined" ){
    style.cssText = style.cssText.replace('foo', 'bar');
}
// Non IE/Edge:
else{
    var style = svgDOC.querySelector("style");
    style.innerHTML = style.innerHTML.replace('foo', 'bar');
}
```

---

**Note:**

It's worth noting that Firefox and other return the actual innerHTML as it is written. If you have no newlines, no newline are in the result:
`.example1{boo:bar;}`

IE and Edge however will return a parsed result.

```
.example1 {
    boo: bar;
}
```